# MATLAB eliminate for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

Is it possible to do the following without a for loop?

```
param1_vary = [-10:5:10]
[r,c] = size(param1_vary)
for i = 1:length(param1_vary)
     new_parms(N,:) = ones(N,c).*param1_vary(i)
end
```

Comment: Please post a runnable example: define all variables; and the line `new_parms(N,:)=...` gives an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay there are two ways I could interpret this:

1. You want a variable `size(new_parms) = [c, N, c]`, where `new_parms(1, :, :) = param_vary(1)` so on and so forth, if this is the case you want to use `ndgrid`

   ```
   param1_vary = [-10:5:10];
   c = length(param1_vary);
   N = 50;

   [new_parms, ~, ~] = ndgrid(param1_vary, ones(N, 1), ones(c,1));
   ```
2. You want a variable `size(new_parms) = [N, c]`, where `new_parms = ones(N, c) * param_vary(1) * param_vary(2) * ...` if this is the case you want the `prod` function

   ```
   param1_vary = [-10:5:10];
   c = length(param1_vary);
   N = 50;
   new_parms = ones(N, c) * prod(param1_vary);
   ```

If neither of these are correct you're going to need to clarify your question.

Comment: Thanks user 1543042! The solution was in the second option. Sorry to everyone for not clarifying my question properly, I kind of wrote this in a rush.